# Which is the most efficient: Kadane's Algorithm or Sliding Window Techniques?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I don't understand exactly why Kadane's Algorithm is a more efficient way of solving maximum subarray type of problems when compared with the sliding window technique.

Comment: How would you know the correct size of the window beforehand?

Comment: @seraph Setay I think you should elaborate more on your thoughts so that others can help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.